# In r, extracting the most common digit in a string

Tags: r

Find most common digit in a string.
Using stringr

- EX: common(122333)
- output : 3 or '3'
- EX: common(I am 29. Born in 1990)
- output: '9' or 9

Answer (score 1):

We can create a function, remove all non-digits, split and return the number with maximum count.

```
common <- function(x) {
   names(which.max(table(strsplit(gsub('\\D', '', x), "")[[1]])))
}

common(123333)
#[1] "3"

common('I am 29. Born in 1990')
#[1] "9"
```

We can also use `str_extract_all` here :

```
common <- function(x) {
  names(which.max(table(stringr::str_extract_all(x, '\\d')[[1]])))
}
```

Comment: is there a way to do it with str_extract_all or str_detect

Comment: We can use `str_extract_all`. I have updated the answer using that.

Comment: is there a way to incorporate str_count as well

Comment: `str_count` is used when we want to count how many times a pattern is repeated. Here we are looking for a specific number that is repeated maximum times which we don't know beforehand.